# using jackson instead of DTO in POST mapping?

Tags: java, rest, jackson

I have the following one to many relationship :

```
public class Product {
        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "product_id_seq", sequenceName = "product_id_seq")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "product_id_seq")
    private Long pid; // initiate it for just a random value in order to hanlde hibernate bug

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="manufacturer",referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator= ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;

   private String name;
   ......more data members...
```

and manufacturer :

```
public class Manufacturer {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "manufacturer_id_seq", sequenceName = "manufacturer_id_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "manufacturer_id_seq")
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String country;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manufacturer",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Product> products;

}
```

my POST body contain the following json :

```
{
    "name":"chocolate",
    "manufacturer": 2,

}
```

Right now I'm using DTO and mapping function to map the productDTO to a product:

```
public class ProductCreationDTO {
    private String name;
    private Long manufacturer;
}

private Product mapProductCreationDTOtoProduct(ProductCreationDTO pcd)
{
    Product p = modelMapper.map(pcd,Product.class); // maps fields with same name that arent nested(like manufacturer)
    Optional<Manufacturer> o = manufacturerService.getManufacturer(pcd.getManufacturer());
    o.ifPresent(m->p.setManufacturer(m));
    return p;
}
```

I suceeded doing this converstion in my get calls for objects by adding those 2 annotations above the manufacturer obj in the Product class:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator= ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
```

Is there a way to using jackson (annotations) to map the post json into a product object (deserialize ) the same it happens during rest get calls(serialize) ?

Comment: I strongly advise not to use persistence entities for data transferring layer. You should stick with the DTO and using conversions between DTOs and entities, or even better between DTO and domain models and between domain models and entities to have cleaner architecture.

Comment: Yeah I guess in aspect of architecture it will far better. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

So instead of using the objectMapper and the DTO I changed the json that I passed to the following :

```
{
    "name":"chocolate",
    "manufacturer": {"id":2}

}
```

Thanks to @Lkopo for the tip - In aspect of architecture it is better to create DTOs in order to transfer data.

Full example with DTO - https://github.com/marielcherkassky/simple_spring_boot_jpa_project